# python mpire: modifying internal state of object within multiprocessing

Tags: python, parallel-processing

I have a class with a method which modifies its internal state, for instance:

```py
class Example():

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.param = value

    def example_method(self, m):
        
        self.param = self.param * m

        # By convention, these methods in my implementation return the object itself
        return self
```

I wanna run `example_method` in parallel (I am using the [mpire](https://slimmer-ai.github.io/mpire/v2.1.0/index.html) lib, but other options are welcome as well), for many instances of `Example`, and have their internal states altered in my instances. Something like:

```py
import mpire

list_of_instances = [Example(i) for i in range(1, 6)]

def run_method(ex):
    ex.example_method(10)

print("Before parallel calls, this should print <1>}")
print(f"<{list_of_instances[0]}>")

with mpire.WorkerPool(n_jobs=3) as pool:
    pool.map_unordered(run_method, [(example,) for example in list_of_instances])

print("After parallel calls, this should print <10>}")
print(f"<{list_of_instances[0]}>")
```

However, the way that `mpire` works, what is being modified are copies of `example`, and not the objects within `list_of_instances`, making any changes to internal state not being kept after the parallel processing. So the second print will print `<1>` instead, because that object`s internal state was not changed, a copy of it was.

I am wondering if there are any solutions to have the internal state changes be applied to the original objects in `list_of_instances`.

The only solutions I can think about is:

- replace `list_of_instances` by the result of `pool.map_unordered` (changing to `pool.map_ordered` if order is important).

Since in any other case (even when using `shared_objects`) I have a copy of the original objects being made, resulting in the state changes being lost.

Is there any way to solve this with parallel processing? I also accept answers using other libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performing multiprocessing every process has it's own memory space and they can't access each other's. The main process can't access the memory of it's children and vice versa.

The only exceptions to this are (given you can't use multithreading):

- When you're using fork as start method and are using `shared_objects`. But, as you mentioned, the objects then are copy-on-write.
- The [shared_memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) module, but this only supports basic types (int, float, bool, str, bytes, None) and a list-like object that is restricted to a fixed length. It doesn't support custom objects. But if you can live with these constraints, then this is a viable option.
- Similar to `shared_memory`, you can use [multiprocessing.Array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array), but this is limited to only a few specific types.

All other options you have all require synchronization and will be slower.

Alternatively, but this depends on what your application looks like exactly, another option could be to use `worker_state` together with the `worker_init` and `worker_exit` functions to create an `Example` object once for each worker, let each worker work on tasks that updates it's own copy of the `Example` object, and return it once all tasks are done. See [documentation](https://slimmer-ai.github.io/mpire/usage/map/worker_init_exit.html#worker-init-exit).

```
def worker_init(worker_state):
    worker_state['example'] = Example(<some_number>)

def worker_exit(worker_state):
    return worker_state['example']

def run_method(worker_state, x):
    worker_state['example'].example_method(x)

with WorkerPool(n_jobs=3, use_worker_state=True) as pool:
    pool.map_unordered(run_method, range(10), 
                       worker_init=worker_init, worker_exit=worker_exit)
    list_of_instances = pool.get_exit_results()
```

This returns as many `Example` instances as the number of jobs in your pool and would require a lot less synchronization. The only synchronization that is done is sending the final object from each worker once all tasks are done.

Lastly, you could use a custom [Manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#customized-managers), register your `Example` object and use that. However, this requires sending data over pipes each time you update a value, which makes it slower again.